# How to delete 5 to 10 records in sqlite in android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

How can I delete records from 5 to 10?

I have used code below but all the records are being deleted instead.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();

for (int i = 5; i <= 10; i++) {
    db.delete(DbHandler.TABLE_USERS, i+"", null);
}
db.close();
```

Comment: In which field this value `i` is stored ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your loop is really doing is this:

```
db.delete(DbHandler.TABLE_USERS, 5+"", null);
db.delete(DbHandler.TABLE_USERS, 6+"", null);
db.delete(DbHandler.TABLE_USERS, 7+"", null);
db.delete(DbHandler.TABLE_USERS, 8+"", null);
db.delete(DbHandler.TABLE_USERS, 9+"", null);
db.delete(DbHandler.TABLE_USERS, 10+"", null);
```

which is equivalent say for the first:

```
delete from DbHandler.TABLE_USERS WHERE '5'
```

This `WHERE '5'` is interpreted by **SQLite** as `WHERE true`, so it deletes all the rows and all the next iterations do the same but there are no rows to delete.
If you want to delete rows with a column value of 5 up to 10, do this without loop:

```
db.delete(DbHandler.TABLE_USERS, columnname between ? and ?, new String[]{"5", "10"});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer meanwhile i got someother answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the whereClause and whereArgs

```
Ex.
delete(String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing the row number is stored on column `_id`. If you have a different column name, just replace by proper column.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
db.delete(DbHandler.TABLE_USERS, "_id >= 5 AND _id <= 10", null);
db.close();
```

or

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
db.delete(DbHandler.TABLE_USERS, "_id >= ? AND _id <= ?", new String[] {"5", "10"});
db.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer meanwhile i got someother answer